# Can Blender support something like OpenTimelineIO?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am an animator who use Synfig (animation) alongside Blender (video editing) and Ardour (audio editing). Though I use some linux-specific scripts and commands to have a common workflow between them, I often create multiple renders, for even for single simple projects, taking awful lot of time. It could be avoided if Blender and other required apps use something like OpenTimelineIO (https://github.com/PixarAnimationStudios/OpenTimelineIO). Is it possible?

Comment: It's possible to write an add-on for this, yes. The question whether Blender *can* support this is unfair, though. It's more a matter of finding people interested in implementing it.